# How to get the Spring XD module class loader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd, javassist

I am using javassist in a Spring XD module. This breaks [since javassist does not use Spring's classpath](http://www.labouisse.com/quicky/2015/09/23/javassisting-spring-boot/). I can work around this by supplying the class loader of the module / XD to javassist. For SpringApplications, I know from the link how to do this. But how can I do this in an XD module, where I do not have a SpringApplication object?

Update: I found a method `createModuleDiscoveryClassLoader` in `ModuleUtils`. However the class loader created there seems not to be accessible from the outside. Does anyone have any other ideas on how to teach Javassist which class loader to use?

Comment: I think it might help if I could get the current Module or SimpleModule I am in. Then I could ask it for its class loader. Is this possible?